# Spring OAuth2 multi Server annotations configuration (resource & authorization)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using the following:

- spring 4.2
- spring security 4.0.2
- spring oauth2 2.0.7

I am trying to configure a single server which handles:

- general MVC stuff (some protected and some not)
- authorization server
- resource server

It seems like the resource server configuration is not limited to /rest/** but is overriding ALL security configuration. i.e calls to protected NON-OAuth resources are not being protected (i.e. the filter is not catching them and redirecting to login).

The configuration (I have removed some stuff fro simplicity):

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter  {



        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .stateless(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**")
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**").access("hasRole('USER') and #oauth2.hasScope('read')");

        }

    }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();

    }
   @Bean
    protected AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName("example");
        return entryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .authenticationProvider(mongoClientAuthenticationProvider)
            .authenticationProvider(mongoUserAuthenticationProvider)
            .userDetailsService(formUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    protected ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter() throws Exception{
        ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter filter = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return filter;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/account/**", "/account")
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token")
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/account/**", "/account").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").access("isFullyAuthenticated()")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/login?authentication_error=true")
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?authentication_error=true")
            .loginPage("/login")
        ;

        http.addFilterBefore(clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using multiple `HttpSecurity` configuration. Spring needs to know the order. Annotate your `SecurityConfig` class with `@Order`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(4)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{}
```

> The annotation `@EnableResourceServer` creates a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a hard-coded Order (of 3). It's not possible to change the order right now owing to technical limitations in Spring, so you must avoid using order=3 in other WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters in your application (Spring Security will let you know if you forget).

Reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html

Comment: I tried with order already but it did not work. You need to notice that the resource class (EnableResourceServer) does not extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Also, how would you decide which one comes first? I need them both to be matched.

Comment: @EnableResourceServer will create WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter automatically with order=3.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is that you should use follow lib(s) version, otherwise you will face this issue.Hope this help.You can't use spring-security 4.0.2 version.
    spring-security-acl-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-config-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-oauth2-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-taglibs-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Can you please explain the reason and basis of the answer?