# Spring http security stop working after adding OAuth2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I added spring security filter to my MVC project with java config. The project have a `/home` method which only allow authenticated user to access.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home").authenticated()
    .and().formLogin()
    .and().httpBasic(); 
}
```

which is working as expected, when I request "http://localhost:8080/project/home" it kicks my out to "/login". After successful login, I can now view "/home"

then I add OAuth2, pretty much same setting as Sparklr2 example

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthServerConfig {
private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "cpe";



@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            // Since we want the protected resources to be accessible in the UI as well we need 
            // session creation to be allowed (it's disabled by default in 2.0.6)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .and()
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/device/**", "/oauth/users/**", "/oauth/clients/**","/me")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/me").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")                  
                .antMatchers("/device").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') or (!#oauth2.isOAuth() and hasRole('ROLE_USER'))")                                        
                //.antMatchers("/device/trusted/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('trust')")
                .antMatchers("/device/user/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('trust')")                 
                .antMatchers("/device/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') or (!#oauth2.isOAuth() and hasRole('ROLE_USER'))")
                .antMatchers("/device/register").access("#oauth2.hasScope('write') or (!#oauth2.isOAuth() and hasRole('ROLE_USER'))")
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/oauth/users/([^/].*?)/tokens/.*")
                    .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/clients/([^/].*?)/users/.*")
                    .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/clients/.*")
                    .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('read')");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;      
    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    //needs to be change
    @Value("${tonr.redirect:http://localhost:8080/tonr2/sparklr/redirect}")
    private String tonrRedirectUri;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        //JdbcClientDetailsServiceBuilder           
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);           
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        //return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm("dragonfly/client");
    }

}

protected static class Stuff {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Bean
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore() throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public DragonflyUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler() throws Exception {
        DragonflyUserApprovalHandler handler = new DragonflyUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setApprovalStore(approvalStore());
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        handler.setUseApprovalStore(true);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

}

with only 1 client detail

```
client.dataSource(dataSource)
    .withClient("my-trusted-client-with-secret")
     .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
     .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
     .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
     .secret("somesecret");
```

I run this on my tomcat server, the OAuth works, I make request to `/oauth/token`, it successfully returns token to me.

I restart my application, then request `/home` without login, it shows up my home view with full content, without login, I couldn't understand. here is the server log when I request `/home`

it try to match OAuth filter first, which has `Order 0`. no match found. then check session, no session found, create a new one. 
then it says it is not OAuth request and no token found.
and it continues down the filter chain, `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`, then granted `ROLE_ANONYMOUS`, by that it response to the request with successful.
which is the opposite to my rule `.antMatchers("/home").authenticated()`

How does that happen?

> 14:40:51.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/oauth/token'] 14:40:51.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/oauth/token' 14:40:51.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/oauth/token_key'] 14:40:51.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/oauth/token_key' 14:40:51.843
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher -
>   Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token'] 14:40:51.843
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/home'; against '/oauth/check_token'
>   14:40:51.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found 14:40:51.843
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher -
>   Trying to match using
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@7926d3d3
>   14:40:51.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - matched 14:40:51.843
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home
>   at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 2 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession
>   currently exists 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext
>   was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 3 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since
>   it did not match the requestMatcher
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3d823ea7
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 4 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/home'; against '/logout' 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home
>   at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter' 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token
>   not found in headers. Trying request parameters. 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token
>   not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request. 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - No token in
>   request, will continue chain. 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 6 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 7 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home
>   at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated
>   SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token:
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc:
>   Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated:
>   true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted
>   Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 9 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 10 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home at position 11 of 11 in
>   additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/me' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/device' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/device/user/**' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/device/**' 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/home'; against '/device/register' 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.RegexRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/home'; against
>   '/oauth/clients/([^/].*?)/users/.*' 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.RegexRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/home'; against '/oauth/clients/.*'
>   14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Public object - authentication
>   not attempted 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /home reached end of additional
>   filter chain; proceeding with original chain 14:40:51.844
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for
>   [/Dragonfly/home] 14:40:51.844 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method
>   for path /home 14:40:51.845 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method
>   [public java.lang.String
>   com.umedia.Dragonfly.controller.HomeController.home()] 14:40:51.845
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory -
>   Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'homeController'
>   14:40:51.845 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for
>   [/Dragonfly/home] is: -1 14:40:51.845 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL
>   [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
>   14:40:51.845 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of
>   singleton bean 'requestDataValueProcessor' 14:40:51.845
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.view.JstlView -
>   Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] in
>   InternalResourceView 'home' 14:40:51.847 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
>   14:40:51.847 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
>   14:40:51.847 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is
>   empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in
>   HttpSession. 14:40:51.847 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now
>   cleared, as request processing completed 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher -
>   Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'] 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/resources/05.jpg'; against
>   '/oauth/token' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant
>   [pattern='/oauth/token_key'] 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/oauth/token_key' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher -
>   Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token'] 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/resources/05.jpg'; against
>   '/oauth/check_token' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - No matches found 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher -
>   Trying to match using
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@7926d3d3
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.matcher.OrRequestMatcher - matched 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /resources/05.jpg at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /resources/05.jpg at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned
>   null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext
>   was available from the HttpSession:
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@ba8ab6a. A new one
>   will be created. 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at position 3 of
>   11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since
>   it did not match the requestMatcher
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3d823ea7
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at position 4 of
>   11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/logout' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /resources/05.jpg at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token
>   not found in headers. Trying request parameters. 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor - Token
>   not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request. 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.o.p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter - No token in
>   request, will continue chain. 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at
>   position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'RequestCacheAwareFilter' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at position 7 of
>   11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /resources/05.jpg at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter -
>   Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token:
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faeba70:
>   Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated:
>   true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId:
>   737F9CEEE6747FABCB433614EF76CF3B; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at position 9 of
>   11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'SessionManagementFilter' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at position 10
>   of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'ExceptionTranslationFilter' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /resources/05.jpg at position 11
>   of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter:
>   'FilterSecurityInterceptor' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/me' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/device' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/resources/05.jpg'; against
>   '/device/user/**' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/device/**' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher -
>   Checking match of request : '/resources/05.jpg'; against
>   '/device/register' 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.RegexRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/oauth/clients/([^/].*?)/users/.*'
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.u.m.RegexRequestMatcher - Checking match of request :
>   '/resources/05.jpg'; against '/oauth/clients/.*' 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor -
>   Public object - authentication not attempted 14:40:51.865
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /resources/05.jpg reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding
>   with original chain 14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/Dragonfly/resources/05.jpg]
>   14:40:51.865 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method
>   for path /resources/05.jpg 14:40:51.866 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler
>   method for [/resources/05.jpg] 14:40:51.866 [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler
>   method for path /resources/05.jpg 14:40:51.866 [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find
>   handler method for [/resources/05.jpg] 14:40:51.866
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -
>   Matching patterns for request [/resources/05.jpg] are [/resources/**]
>   14:40:51.866 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request
>   [/resources/05.jpg] are {} 14:40:51.866 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/resources/05.jpg] to
>   HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler
>   [locations=[ServletContext resource [/resources/]],
>   resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@20458412]]]
>   and 1 interceptor 14:40:51.866 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for
>   [/Dragonfly/resources/05.jpg] is: -1 14:40:51.867
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null
>   ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher':
>   assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 14:40:51.867
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -
>   Successfully completed request 14:40:51.867 [http-nio-8080-exec-7]
>   DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
>   14:40:51.867 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is
>   empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in
>   HttpSession. 14:40:51.867 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now
>   cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: I have log which stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post, it says it looks like spam.

Comment: You have multiple HttpSecurity configuration, use `@Order(1)` in your security configuration class which filter the `/home`. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206843/spring-oauth2-multi-server-annotations-configuration-resource-authorization

Comment: you are right, that is exactly the problem. I know that OAuth2 is using Order(0), but I did not know I have to specify Order(1) to work with it. thank you so much.

Comment: after testing my oauth resources, adding Order(1) to my security will break my oauth resources protection. that is, all my security setting in `ResourceServerConfiguration` is skipped. my oauth resource are now accessible without any authentication and authorization. maybe something else needs to be done to work with this Order(1)?

Comment: your order value should be above 3, this is because OAuth has order=3. Try to annotate it with `Order(4)`

Comment: I've tried order 4. it will acts like the mvc security filter does not exist. maybe something wrong with my filter chain setup, they are not chained  together, but replace one another instead. if the order is less than 3, it will be solely mvc security, otherwise if order larger than 3, only oauth security is active.

Comment: maybe you should put all of your updated security configuration here

Comment: I put my source here 
https://github.com/maxiwu/springoauthsecurity-jc

Comment: more test result.

oauth security is at order 3. I tried both mvc security order <3 and >3, the tomcat log reveal some information.

case 1, order <3
the filter FilterSecurityInterceptor will match the request with mvc security, which will find a match, for exmaple /home, and redirect me to login page.

case 2 order >3
the filter FilterSecurityInterceptor will match the request against oauth, like /photos, /me, but will not found any match, then the request reach the end of chain. this request is response as if there is no security filter, since it does not find any match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have problems with your project setup and pom configuration

1. You added spring boot dependencies, yet you don't use spring boot.
2. Your project is package as jar, yet you you have WEB-INF and use `WebApplicationInitializer` rather than spring boot
3. Your pom dependencies is wrong

I have modified several things:

1. move `WebContent` folder and rename it to `src/main/webapp`
2. update your pom configuration

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.umedia</groupId>
   <artifactId>Dragonfly</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>Dragonfly</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>junit</groupId>
           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
           <version>3.8.1</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.5</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.0</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
           <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
           <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.1</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
           <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.7</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.7</source>
                   <target>1.7</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <path>/</path>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
       <finalName>liveBLE</finalName>
   </build>
   </project>
   ```

run it using `mvn tomcat7:run`. If I access `/home` I will be redirected to login page and if I access `/device` i will get

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

This is the expected behavior using OAuth and Spring security.

Comment: Mang, you are right, you fix works perfectly.
I do not know that my project settings is messing with spring security, my fault. I didn't really know how to package a project, will work on that. thank you so much

Comment: I have further test this, with war package and tomcat7:run, it runs as expected. If I debug project war with eclipse m2eclipse plugin, and target java 1.8, the problem still exists. could that be a plugin problem or java 1.8 problem? could you kindly test with eclipse debug on server?

Comment: what tomcat version you used in eclipse? I have tried using jdk 1.8 and tomcat 8 in eclipse and still works. There some issue if you run with jdk 1.8 and tomcat 7 though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541532/tomcat7-and-java8-wont-start